# Dev loop0: unable to read RDB block 8

Tags: dmesg

Every time I boot my laptop I see this warning and from **dmesg** I get this output:

```
[    2.895604] Dev loop0: unable to read RDB block 8
[    2.895641]  loop0: unable to read partition table
[    2.895936] loop0: partition table beyond EOD, truncated
```

What does this warning means? Should I be worried? I have an SSD and it seems to be working well.

I saw that RDB means Rigid Disk Block from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amiga_rigid_disk_block).

When I run **fdisk -l** I get

```
Disc /dev/loop0: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Unities: sector of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logic/physic): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimal/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

Answer (score 5):

From Unix & Linux, Alex [said](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/710035/dev-loop0-unable-to-read-rdb-block-8):

> The loop0 device is only 4kB in size, which is 8 blocks of 512 bytes.

> The driver for the RDB partition table format tries to read the first 8 kB (16 blocks), because the RDB can be in any of them. While it does that, it reads past the end of the loop device.

> This is harmless, and probably went unnoticed because block devices this small are unusual.